# Problemas al mostrar datos de un array en un select en Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

tengo el siguiente array en:

```
  var GruposSanguineos = [
{
    Nombre: '0 RH(+)',
    Valor: '0+'
},
{
    Nombre: '0 RH(-)',
    Valor: '0-'
},
{
    Nombre: 'A RH(+)',
    Valor: 'A+'
},
{
    Nombre: 'A RH(-)',
    Valor: 'A-'
},
{
    Nombre: 'B RH(+)',
    Valor: 'B+'
},
{
    Nombre: 'B RH(-)',
    Valor: 'B-'
},
{
    Nombre: 'AB RH(+)',
    Valor: 'AB+'
},
{
    Nombre: 'AB RH(-)',
    Valor: 'AB-'
},
```

];

Llamo al array en mi controller asi:

```
     $scope.datosLicencia = {
        Constantes: {
        GruposSanguineos: GruposSanguineos,
                    },
        NuevosDatos: {},
                             };
```

Lo muestro en la vista en un select de la siguiente forma:

```
    <tr>
        <th class="col-md-3 text-right">Grupo Sanguineo</th>
        <td class="col-md-9">
            <select class="form-control" name="GrupoSanguineo" id="GrupoSanguineo" ng-model="datosLicencia.NuevosDatos.GrupoSanguineo" ng-options="GrupoSanguineo.Valor as GrupoSanguineo.Nombre for GrupoSanguineo in datosLicencia.Constantes.GruposSanguineos" required>
                 <option value=""></option>
             </select>
         </td>
    </tr>
```

Traigo el valor del select del ws asi:

```
    WSAPP.ConsultaSOAP(Consulta).then(function (response) {
    if (!response.CodError) {
        $scope.datosLicencia.NuevosDatos.GrupoSanguineo = response.GrupoSanguineo;
    } else {
        bootbox.alert($scope.datos.Errores[response.CodError]);
    }
    $.skylo('end');
});
```

y obtengo el valor del select asi:

```
     Consulta = {
        URL: webServiceLicencias,
        Metodo: 'ActualizarLicencia',
        Parametros: $scope.datosLicencia.NuevosDatos,
    };
```

El problema es el siguiente: cuando entro a la vista tendria que mostrarte asi

[image: MOstrar asi]

pero me muestra asi

[image: muestra asi aquí]

Como lo resuelvo?

Comment: probaste usando `trackBy`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions lo otro, no es necesario poner un `<option></option>`

Comment: ya probe el `track By` y no me funciono

Comment: la línea `$scope.datosLicencia.NuevosDatos.GrupoSanguineo = response.GrupoSanguineo;` en que formato viene? ten en cuenta que tu modelo, para el valor `GrupoSanguineo` debe calzar en formato con el `value` de los `option`

Comment: me la devuelve asi `{
  "GrupoSanguineo": "A RH(+)", 
}` pero pasa que se compara con el valor no con el nombre, por eso no me lo muestra no se como hacer que compare con nombre y siga enviando el valor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta solución es muy acoplada a tu problemática. Lo que haría es: recibir el valor, filtrar sobre el conjunto original y setear en base a esto el modelo. Algo así:

```
WSAPP.ConsultaSOAP(Consulta).then(function (response) {
  if (!response.CodError) {
    // Primero busco todos los grupos sanguíneos que calcen con el valor de response
    var grupo = GruposSanguineos.filter(function(item) {
      return item.Nombre == response.GrupoSanguineo;
    });
    // Debiese ser solo uno, no? así que le seteo su valor
    $scope.datosLicencia.NuevosDatos.GrupoSanguineo = grupo[0].Valor;

  } else {
      bootbox.alert($scope.datos.Errores[response.CodError]);
  }
});
```

Así te mantienes utilizando `Valor` y no necesitas hacer más cambios en otros lugares el código

Comment: Me funciono el código que me sugeriste

Answer (score 2):

Otra opción es simplemente en el ng-model del select agregar .Valor quedando así:
ng-model="datosLicencia.NuevosDatos.GrupoSanguineo.Valor" esto funciona si 
$scope.datosLicencia.NuevosDatos.GrupoSanguineo se llena(cuando ejecutas WSAPP.ConsultaSOAP(Consulta)) con un objeto que exista en el array GruposSanguineos.

**Corrección**:
Para que te funcione la response.GrupoSanguineo debe ser equivalente al Valor en el array Ejemplo: response.GrupoSanguineo = { "GrupoSanguineo": "A+"} y NO como tu lo llenas en este momento { "GrupoSanguineo": "A RH(+)"} y sin agregar el .Valor como yo lo había indicado.

Comment: Eso no me funciono, lo probé y simplemente no funciono, razón por la cual hice la pregunta

Comment: yo lo probé y me funciono. tu en ng-model no le agregaste .Valor  y si puedes mostrar lo que retorna response.GrupoSanguineo para identificar si ahí es el error.

Comment: Oh ya vi como retorna la response.GrupoSanguineo y es por eso que no te funciona, por que el option tiene una propiedad llamada Value y ese es el que debe ser igual a lo que hay en en el array con la propiedad Valor. Ejemplo response.GrupoSanguineo = { "GrupoSanguineo": "A+"} para que te funcione esa debería ser la respuesta y sin agregar .Valor como te había dicho en la primera respuesta.

Comment: el options ya lo elimine, la otra respuesta es la que me funciono y perfectamente